# Get just one of a divs IDS with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div with more than one ID and I need to get each ID separately and send both variables off to a PHP file. I feel this would be the simpler option if achievable but the other option is to split the two IDS on the server side with PHP once the ID has been sent to it by jQuery. One ID is the timestamp the other the ID in the database.

HTML div example:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;" id="1000003 2012-09-04 21:24:32" class="newsItem"></div>
```

The 1000003 is the ID i need to get into one separate variable and the rest is the timestamp I need in another separate variable.

The jQuery I have:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
     //scripting here
 var obj = $('.newsItem:first').map(function(_, elem){
         return elem.id;
     });

     var ids = $.makeArray(obj); //variable of IDS
     $.get("AJAX/get_feed_updates.php",{ ids: ids },function(result){
         $("#newsFeed").html(result);
     }); 
     }, 5000);
```

The PHP file just puts the ID into a variable and queries the database with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [data](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attribute. Then you can do something like this..

```
<div data-timestamp="1000003 2012-09-04 21:24:32" id="myId"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store one in the [DATA](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attribute. [Here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) is another reference to how its used.

Comment: Preferebly the "timestamp", because IDs are not allowed to contain whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Is this right?

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
 //scripting here

 var theId = $('.newsItem:first').attr('id');
 var a = theId.split(' ');
 var theId = a[0];
 var theStamp = a[1]+''+a[2];

 $.get("AJAX/get_feed_updates.php",{ ids: theId },function(result){

 $("#newsFeed").html(result);
 }); 


 }, 5000);
```